# Is there any way to output the filtered data from Zend_Filter_Input?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there any way to output all filtered data from the class Zend_Filter_Input?

Comment: How do you mean? The filtered data? Why? $data = $myFilter->filter($data); is not direct enough?

Comment: $_data: array Input data, **before** processing. Why would you need that value?

Comment: To tharkun: Yes, I need the filtered data but Zend_Filter_Input doesn't have a filter() function

Comment: To smoove666: Sorry I have made a mistake. Actually I need the data after processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zend_Filter_Input` offers numerous methods for retrieving filtered and validated data.
First, you can retrieve an associative array of all fields:

```
$data = $input->getEscaped(); // Retrieve all data, escaped with Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities
$data = $input->getUnescaped(); // Retrieve all data, not escaped.
```

You can also get an associative array of certain segments of you data, the method names are very clear:

```
  $invalidFields = $input->getInvalid(); // Fields that failed validation

  $missingFields = $input->getMissing(); // Fields that were declared as 'required' using the 'presence' metacommand, but not in the input

  $unknownFields = $input->getUnknown(); // Fields that were not declared in the validator rules, but were present in the input.
```

On top of all that, `Zend_Filter_Input` offers an object accessor, through an implementation of the `__get` magic method:

```
$oneField = $input->oneFieldName
```

Answer (score -1):

In form you can get unfiltered values. Check the manual ;)

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake. I need to get an array storing all filtered data.